# Does anyone know how I can model hair like this?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I like the stylization in the hair of this character but I do y know the process to follow to get the style. If you have any ideas feel free to say. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can duplicate the faces of its head, then separate as a new object:

[image]

Extrude the edges to create the strands:

[image]

Give it a *Solidify* modifier and apply it:

[image]

Make the extremities thinner, etc:

[image]

Comment: nice!!! The master works on weekends as well....+1

Comment: Hello Chris, thanks but as I told you I've got a whole team 100% dedicated to BSE's answers, and now we are growing worldwide, this is crazy

Comment: By the way you should better buy some Moonboots International stock options RIGHT NOW

Comment: Ok, what’s your stock‘s symbol? I don’t know what to do with the billions on my bank account and now the inflation shrinks it like hell…